# External Page Displaying Properties of [If (Home Page)]

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have a slider that displays only on our homepage with the following condition

```
<?php if( is_home() ) : ?>
```

It works properly with one exception, external pages located outside of the sites main folder that call the header display the slider as well.

Is there a way to designate a page as "not home/front"?

Comment: I'll see if they can help any further. I was hoping this was relevant to php more so than wordpress builds, but I could be wrong.

Comment: "External pages" would be something like a page level "root"? You want to add this condition to the "pages" or "php files"? 
Are there any files beyond the "index.php" and "xmlrpc.php" that can be accessed directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php is_front_page(); ?>
```

change is_home() to that and it should fix it right up.

Comment: It's still displaying on the "external" (outside of the main site's folder) pages. Just for clarity, I changed the code to the following

    <?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>

Comment: Did you put that code on the main page? or where its including the code for the slider?

Comment: I have both the conditional statement and the slider html within header.php, neither code is in the index.  
  
**EDIT This is due to the fact that the outer wrapper is located within the header as well**

Comment: then you should put that in header. Wherever the slider is so that function will just show the slider on the main page

Comment: Both pieces of code are located in the header. The conditional statement is working on 99% of the pages in my site, but landing pages that I create outside of the site folder act as if they're the home page also.

Comment: Would you mind linking me to a page thats working correctly and ones that not?

Comment: Sure thing. [Front Page Displaying Slider](http://www.beststuff.com), [Non front page working properly](http://www.beststuff.com/category/audio/bluetooth-speakers/), [Non front page incorrectly displaying slider](http://www.beststuff.com/searchformtest.php)

Comment: It looks like you do not have access to is_front_page() on the other pages. Look at the code for both and see if theres anything on one thats not on the other that has to do with wordpress

Comment: I appreciate the help Nicholas. I'll try and dive deeper into any possible differences